# Adjusting position of labels in a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Apologies if this question is trivial, I've created a side `geom_bar` plot and I'm just trying to figure out how I can adjust the positioning of the percentage labels. I would like to have each label either just outside each sidebar, or just inside (but not overlapping inside and outside like in the image below)

Here is my dataset `bars`

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(18577, 18577, 18577, 18577, 
18577, 18577, 18577, 18577, 18577, 18577), class = "Date"), Ticker = c("ARS", 
"BRL", "IDR", "INR", "MXN", "NGN", "RUB", "THB", "TRY", "ZAR"
), Return = c(-7.1, 2.1, 3.5, -0.8, 7.3, 1.3, -3.3, 2.5, -10.5, 
8)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

and my code below

```
p1 <- ggplot(bars, aes(Ticker,Return,fill=Ticker)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom') +
  labs(title = '% Change in EM Currencies vs USD since September 1',
       subtitle = 'Performance of EM Currencies has diverged recently',
       y = '% Change since September 1', x = '') +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,linetype = 'dashed',
             col = 'black',size = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(Return,"%")))


p1
```

[image]

Comment: [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46300666/put-labels-over-negative-and-positive-geom-bar), this is very similar problem, it can mostly be controlled within your `geom_text` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My method is slightly less efficient than the other answer but still gets the job done. I created two conditional `geom_text` calls and adjusted hjust to get the values outside of the bars. Also had to expand the limits a little bit to make room for the labels on the tallest bars.

```r
library(tidyverse)

bars <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18577, 18577, 18577, 18577, 
                                  18577, 18577, 18577, 18577, 18577, 18577), class = "Date"), 
               Ticker = c("ARS","BRL", "IDR", "INR", "MXN", "NGN", "RUB", "THB", "TRY", "ZAR"), 
               Return = c(-7.1, 2.1, 3.5, -0.8, 7.3, 1.3, -3.3, 2.5, -10.5, 8)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

position = position_dodge(width = -.75)
width =-.75
                                                                                           
p1 <- ggplot(bars, aes(Ticker,Return,fill=Ticker)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom') +
  labs(title = '% Change in EM Currencies vs USD since September 1',
       subtitle = 'Performance of EM Currencies has diverged recently',
       y = '% Change since September 1', x = '') +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,linetype = 'dashed',
             col = 'black',size = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(Return < 0, paste0(Return,"%"), "")), hjust = 1.1) +
  geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(Return > 0, paste0(Return,"%"), "")), hjust = -0.2) +
  expand_limits(y = -12, x = 12)


p1
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `hjust` argument in `geom_text`

```
geom_text(aes(label=paste0(Return,"%"), hjust="left"))
```